# Matlab: Apply a function to each block of a 4D matrix

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix containing a sequence of images and I want to apply an function to each block of this sequence. The matrix has size [480 640 3 56] and the blocks have size [8 8 1 8]. `blockproc` supports only images. The function returns a block of same size so the result will be another sequence with same size.

Comment: Do you have a specific function in mind?

Comment: It's a 3D spectral transformation like DCT.

Comment: Reshape into `8 x 8 x 1 x 8 x N` shape and then apply the function in a loop?

Comment: That would work, but it's not faster than 4 loops, one for each dimension. It needs 24 seconds per computation.

Comment: Maybe your DCT function could be vectorized? Are you allowed to share here? Or else try function-inlining.

Comment: Now I'm working with the first answer with cells and it looks promising.

Comment: Let me know if it works. Also, I have a series of `rows2cell`/`cols2cell`/`slices2cell` functions to run `cellfun` on. Just ping me if you want a copy of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First reshape your original data into the necessary size. Then you can use my custom cubes2cell.m function then use `cellfun` to execute your function on each cube.

```
function C = cubes2cell( A )
    %% cubes2cell( A )
    % 
    % Inputs
    % A - Matrix to split into cube matrices stored as cells
    % 
    % Outputs
    % C - Cell with each element a sequential row of A

    %% Use mat2cell to perform conversion with appropriate dimensions
    C = squeeze( mat2cell( A, size(A,1), size(A,2), size(A,3), ones(1,size(A,4)) ) );
```

Suppose your data was in `M` and your function was called `fun`. Then you would call your code using:

```
result = cellfun( @fun, cubes2cell( M ), 'UniformOutput', false )
```